# MYSQL subquery SELECT in JOIN clause

Tags: mysql, subquery

Ok... well I have to put the subquery in a `JOIN` clause since it selects more than one column and putting it in the `SELECT` clause does not allow that as it gives me an error of an operand.
Anywho, this is my query:

```sql
SELECT 
    c.id, 
    c.title, 
    c.description, 
    c.icon, 
    p.id as topic_id, 
    p.title AS topic_title, 
    p.date, 
    p.username
FROM forum_cat c
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                ft.id, 
                ft.cat_id, 
                ft.title, 
                fp.date, 
                u.username
            FROM forum_topic ft
                JOIN forum_post fp ON fp.topic_id = ft.id
                JOIN user u ON u.user_id = fp.author_id
            WHERE ft.cat_id = c.id
            ORDER BY fp.date DESC
            LIMIT 1
         ) p ON p.cat_id = c.id
WHERE c.main_cat = ?
ORDER BY c.list_no
```

Now the important thing I need here... `FOR EACH` category, I want to show the latest post and topic title in each category.
However, this select statement is going INSIDE a foreach loop looping around the general categories which is found my main_cat.
So there are 5 main categories with 3-8 subcategories.. this is the subcategory query. BUT FOR EACH subcategory, I need to grab the latest post.. However, it only runs this SELECT query for each main category so it's only select THE LATEST post between all subcategories combined... I want to get the latest post of EACH subcategory, but I rather not run this query for each subcategory... since I want the page load to be fast.
BUT REMEMBER, some subcategories WILL NOT have a latest post since some of them may not even contain a topic yet! So hence the left join.

Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

AND BTW, there is an error it gives me `(WHERE ft.cat_id = c.id)` in the subquery because `c.id` is an unknown column. But I'm trying to reference it from the outer query so can someone help me on that issue as well?

Thank you!

All tables:

```
forum_cat (Subcategories)
-----------------------------------------------
ID, Title, Description, Icon, Main_cat, List_no

forum_topic (Topics in each subcategory)
--------------------------------------------
ID, Author_id, Cat_id, Title, Sticky, Locked

forum_post (Posts in each topic)
--------------------------------------------
ID, Topic_id, Author_id, Body, Date, Hidden'
```

The main categories are listed in a function. I didn't store them in the database since it was a waste of space since they never change. There are 7 main categories though.

Comment: This looks very like a groupwise max query - the kind that gets asked in SO about 10 times per day. That said, if browsing recent questions genuinely doesn't get you anywhere, consider providing DDLs for ALL relevant tables. (I doubt that you need the foreach)

Comment: Ok well I'll edit my response. I browsed EVERYWHERE, but my query is a lot different than all others that are posted due to the LIMIT in the subquery...

Comment: Like Strawberry mentioned in order to let people help you make their lives easier creating [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with appropriate DDL and sample data

Comment: @Peanut: it is not different, and the limit clause is wrong. You can use any standard solution such as finding min(fp.date) and joining to it.

Comment: @Peterm.. I've TRIED EVERYTHING to make that SQLFiddle work.... I have no idea how to work it... I pasted all my SQL to create my tables on the left side, click Build Schema, ran the SQL file on the right side. And it gave me this error: Table 'db_2_6ff8b.user doesn't exist'

Comment: @Peanut Use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and one of us can move it to a fiddle.

Answer (score 28):

It's hard to tell without seeing DDL of your tables, relevant sample data and desired output.

I could've got your requirements wrong, but try this:

```sql
SELECT *  
  FROM forum_cat c LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT t.cat_id, 
               p.topic_id, 
               t.title, 
               p.id, 
               p.body, 
               MAX(p.`date`) AS `date`, 
               p.author_id, 
               u.username
          FROM forum_post p INNER JOIN
               forum_topic t ON t.id = p.topic_id INNER JOIN
               `user` u ON u.user_id = p.author_id
         GROUP BY t.cat_id) d ON d.cat_id = c.id
 WHERE c.main_cat = 1
 ORDER BY c.list_no
```