# MySQL Multiple Join Query with Limit on One Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a **MYSQL** query I'm working on that pulls data from multiple joins.

```
select students.studentID, students.firstName, students.lastName, userAccounts.userID, userstudentrelationship.userID, userstudentrelationship.studentID, userAccounts.getTexts, reports.pupID, contacts.pfirstName, contacts.plastName, reports.timestamp

 from userstudentrelationship  

join userAccounts on (userstudentrelationship.userID = userAccounts.userID)
join students on (userstudentrelationship.studentID = students.studentID) 
join reports on (students.studentID = reports.studentID) 
join contacts on (reports.pupID = contacts.pupID) 

where userstudentrelationship.studentID = "10000005" AND userAccounts.getTexts = 1 ORDER BY reports.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

I have a unique situation where I would like one of the joins (the reports join)  to be limited to the latest result only for that table (order by reports.timestamp desc limit 1 is what I use), while not limiting the result quantities for the overall query.

By running the above query I get the data I would expect, but only one record when it should return several.

My question:

How can I modify this query to ensure that I receive all possible records available, while ensuring that only the latest record from the reports join used? I expect that each record will possibly contain different data from the other joins, but all records returned by this query will share the same report record

Comment: What do you use? MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: MySQL. I'll update question.

Comment: @waka updated..

Comment: so confusing ... do you wish JUST SINGLE record, or one record per group? For example student can have several reports, but the only record you are interesting for that student is the latest entered report

Comment: What Dmitrij points out confuses me as well. If you join contacts on reports, you'll only have that one contact if you just have one record returned from reports... other than that, you can actually use `JOIN` on a subselect like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483739/mysql-subquery-select-in-join-clause)

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Sorry, I've made it a little more complicated than it should be. 

The contacts will not change as it is based on the report. A student can several contacts, but they wont appear in this report, but were only pulling the contact or pupID that is listed in the single report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided I understand the issue; one could add a join to a set of data (aliased Z below) that has the max timestamp for each student; thereby limiting to one report record (most recent) for each student.

```
SELECT students.studentID
     , students.firstName
     , students.lastName
     , userAccounts.userID
     , userstudentrelationship.userID
     , userstudentrelationship.studentID
     , userAccounts.getTexts
     , reports.pupID
     , contacts.pfirstName
     , contacts.plastName
     , reports.timestamp
FROM userstudentrelationship  
join userAccounts 
  on userstudentrelationship.userID = userAccounts.userID
join students 
  on userstudentrelationship.studentID = students.studentID
join reports 
  on students.studentID = reports.studentID
join contacts 
  on reports.pupID = contacts.pupID
join (SELECT max(timestamp) mts, studentID 
      FROM REPORTS 
      GROUP BY StudentID) Z
  on reports.studentID = Z.studentID
 and reports.timestamp = Z.mts
WHERE userstudentrelationship.studentID = "10000005" 
  AND userAccounts.getTexts = 1 
ORDER BY reports.timestamp
```

Comment: This answer resolved it perfectly. Thank you! I think I under explained the situation so it confused some people, but I didn't want a TLDR moment. The contact result would never change, because there is only one possible contact in the report result. The only thing can truly change is the userAccounts.

Comment: if all you were after was max timestmap we could have just grouped by the other fields and used aggregation; but because you needed the pupID from reports as well; we needed additional information about that specific max report record per student.

Answer (score 1):

for get all the records you should avoid limit 1 at the end of the query
for join anly one row from reports table you could use subquery as

```
select 
    students.studentID
    , students.firstName
    , students.lastName
    , userAccounts.userID
    , userstudentrelationship.userID
    , userstudentrelationship.studentID
    , userAccounts.getTexts
    , t.pupID
    , contacts.pfirstName
    , contacts.plastName
    , t.timestamp

from userstudentrelationship  

join userAccounts on userstudentrelationship.userID = userAccounts.userID
join students on userstudentrelationship.studentID = students.studentID
join (
  select * from reports
  order by reports.timestamp  limit 1
) t on students.studentID = t.studentID
join contacts on reports.pupID = contacts.pupID 

where userstudentrelationship.studentID = "10000005" 
AND userAccounts.getTexts = 1
```

Comment: this will give 1 single record for every student. I think that he wishes to get the latest report for each student